# Unable to rotate an image in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, editor, material-ui, avatar

I'm working on React-Avatar Editor. My rotate button is not functioning as expected. Here's my link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/example-for-react-avatar-editor-ofoz4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You weren't using the rotate value. I've fixed it in this fork:

https://codesandbox.io/s/example-for-react-avatar-editor-dc6wh

```
              <AvatarEditor
                rotate={this.state.rotate}
              />
```

Also I've removed the `rotate=0` in the rotation functions. Don't know if you want to rotate it completely or just once in every direction